# Prolog recursing endlessly in getList predicate

Tags: list, prolog

This predicate is intended to tell if the list has the element in it and add it to a new list. However, once I finish recursing through and I have the correct list being returned, it recurses backwards until it ends up at the beginning again and then recurses through it again -- endlessly.

```
getList([],X,[]).
getList([H|T],Side,Others) :-
    (length(T,3)),
    (H == Side),
    append([],[H],NewList),
    getList(T,Side,NewList).
getList([H|T],Side,Others) :-
    (H == Side),
    append(Others, [Side], Others1),
    getList(T,Side,Others1). // where it backwards recurses after finishing
getList([E],X,[]).
```

Please help me determine WHY it does this as well as find a solution.

Comment: What's the significance of `length(T, 3)` in the logic? Your 2nd and 3rd clauses will *both* succeed when the length of `T` is 3, so backtracking will explore both options.

Comment: In what mode does it exhibit this behaviour? What's the exact query?

Comment: Please provide some sample queries together with the expected answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your description of the predicate right it searches in the first list for the element(s) **identical** to the `Element` and copies the `Element` in the second list.

This predicate can be implemented as follows:

*getList( Element, OldList,  NewList ).*

```
getList( Element, [], [] ).
getList( Element, [ X | Xs ], [ Element | Ys ]) :- 
  X == Element, 
  getList( Element, Xs, Ys ).

getList( Element, [ X | Xs ], Ys ) :- 
%  X \== Element, 
  getList( Element, Xs, Ys ).
```

The following query is succeded with the result `NewList`

```
?- getList( a(X), [ a(1), a(a), a(Y), a(X), b(Y), a(X) ], NewList ).

yes
NewList = [ a(X), a(X) ].
```

**P.S.** `length( X, 3 )` will give you `[ _ , _ , _ ]` if `X` is an unbound variable.